# Configure a router to support two private networks

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, vlan, private-network

I have a ZTE modem/router and I want to have 2 interfaces related to two privates networks: 192.168.1.0  192.168.2.0 with gateways 192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1, at the same time I need both interfaces to be connected to the internet (WAN), an be able to communicate between them. The Pc choose if they want to belong to the net 192.168.2.0 by static IP, otherwise the dhcp will give an IP in 192.168.1.0 by default.

```
                     ________
PC| ->192.168.2.1-> |        |
                    | Router |-> WAN
PC| ->192.168.1.1-> |________|
```

How can I achieve that with only one router/modem?

**EDIT**

It must work whether the devices are connected thru physical LAN or WLAN.

Router model: `ZXV10 W300`

Comment: Does the modem/router support VLANs?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes it does but not sure if it support advanced settings, btw it's a  ZXV10 W300

Comment: How does it handle VLANS? Do you tag the ports or is it just an "enable VLAN" option? Router model would be handy!

Comment: @Lister i edited the question to add the model. "Assign VLAN PVID for each Interface" " Define VLAN Group" only

Comment: But why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments your router can use VLANS by using PVIDs.
What this means is that the router will tag the physical Ethernet port (The one you plug the network cable into) as part of a vlan.

Lets take your example. If I was to mark the port that 192.168.1.1 is plugged into as VLAN 1 and the port that 192.168.2.1 is plugged into as VLAN 2, it will segregate them.

If I add another device and plug him into another port and make him 192.168.2.2 VLAN 2 then those two devices will be in the same VLAN.

If I add a fourth device and make him 192.168.2.3 but I don't tag him, he cannot talk with 192.168.2.1 or .2

Your router may have an option to determine if communication between the vlans is allowed. If not, the VLANs may be isolated from each other.

Comment: I don't want to assign a vlan to a physical port, neither for wlan, two pc both conncted thru wlan can be in different networks. From what i understand once i tagged/assign a vlan to wlan all devices connected thru wlan will be in the same net, which i don't want.

Comment: Looking at your router model you can set multiple SSIDs, and have two connected to different Vlans. Its a bit of a dirty job doing it with consumer equiptment. Whats your end goal? I may be able to help better then.

Comment: I am only restricted to one in `SSID Index`, I am not even sure if it's possible with only one router I am open to introduce a switch but before what i want is to isolate some devices in a another net or subnet to be able to broadcast them alone without reaching not concerned devices

Comment: Broadcast traffic isnt a significant concern unless you have hundreds of devices. But if you still want to in that case, a layer 3 switch would be the most useful to you. We are doing the same but on a larger scale where I work. You would plug devices into the layer 3 switch, and assign their ports a vlan tag. The switch will block broadcasts between vlans, but would still allow direct traffic between hosts if you configure it to do so. Then the router would not have to get involved.